# how to use a forloop such that the if the "IF" statement in the loop is satisfied the loop ends in Django Templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 Django models `Review` and `Item` that I am working with. I want to see if the user has already reviewed the item. If yes he sees the review score. if no he sees the button to review the item

I have the below Review model

```
class Review (models.Model):
    review_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_from')
    review_for = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_for')
    item = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, related_name='items')
```

Defining the variables in the view context (pseudocode)

```
admin = User.objects.get(username="admin")
admins_reviews = Review.objects.filter(review_from__username = "admin")
```

Below is my template

```
 {% for item in buyers_items %}
    {% for review in buyers_review%}
         {% if review.item.id == item.id %}
              <button class="text-success">Your rating<br/><b>{{review.ratings}}/10</b></button>
         {% else %}
              <a href="{% url ... %}">
                <button>Leave Review</button>
              </a>
          {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I do this I get a below error

[image]

How can I overcome this problem.

View

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

class OrderHistory(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'order/order_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderHistory, self).get_context_data()
        context['order_details'] = Order.objects.filter(emailAddress=self.request.user.email)
        context['order_items'] = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__emailAddress=self.request.user.email)
        context['buyers_review'] = Review.objects.filter(review_from=self.request.user)
        print(context['buyers_review'])
        return context
```

Custom Tag

```
    @register.filter()
    def review_bought_items(order_items, buyers_review):
        return buyers_review.filter(item__in=order_items).exists()
```

Comment: It's not clear what error you're getting?

Comment: @JonClements I have edited the image. I am getting 2 buttons one with the review and one that says leave review. See above image. SInce they both have reviews.

Comment: All these logic must be done in your back-end, not in the template side. Show your view, so I can help

Comment: If you c/p the html template, you have a typo at the {% endif %} tag.

Comment: @Alex I fixed it is correct in the actual code

Comment: @Lemayzeur I agree I will work on that too. But for now. Do you think I have way around this in the templates

Comment: With a custom tag filter you may do it. like `{% if buyers_items|intersection:buyers_review %} ....` then you run your code with the tag function

Comment: @Lemayzeur that code looks really interesting could you possibly add it in a answer so I can see exactly how you mean. I am working on it too.

Comment: @Lemayzeur I am getting this error `Invalid filter: 'intersection'

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I see in your templates, you could do it simpler with a tag filter or in your view side. Let's go with a custom tag:

```
@register.filter
def review_bought_items(buyers_items,buyers_review):
     return buyers_review.filter(item__in=buyers_items).exists()
```

Now in the templates you could do

```
<!-- load the tag -->
{% load file %}

{% if buyers_items|review_bought_items:buyers_review %}
     <button class="text-success">Your rating<br/><b>{{review.ratings}}/10</b></button>
{% else %}
     <a href="{% url ... %}">Leave Review</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have edited my views (see question above) as per your code does that look correct to you.

Comment: No @SamirTendulkar it's not correct, the custom tag should be a separated file, take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) to see how to write a custom tag

Comment: I am sure it will work, just took a dinner break. Will watch videos on custom tag and implement it tomorrow I can't thank you enough for answering this

Comment: Ok glad to help!

Comment: Still working on this. The `{{review.ratings}}` only works because of the forloop `{% for review in buyers_review%}` If I add a forloop in your code. Its like I am back to square 1. I am sure I am doing something wrong. This is my personal project so have to work on this between my day job. Hopefully will work all night on this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are iterating over all `buyers_reviews`. In this particular case, you have 2 buyer reviews, one for the current item and one for a different one.

First iteration will evaluate to `False` the first condition and it will display all the `Leave Review` button and the 2nd iteration will evaluate it to `True` and display the "Your rating" block.

If you don't want to move all the logic on the backend, maybe make us of a template tag in order to filter the reviews based on `item.id`

Comment: I tried to filter it in the views currently my views are `context['buyers_review'] = Review.objects.filter(review_from=self.request.user)`  I am not sure how to filter the item `context['buyers_review'] = Review.objects.filter(review_from=self.request.user, item=self.kwargs.get("item"))` did not work

Comment: I don't know how your full view looks like but, you could use the solution recommended in the comments section and create a custom filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) and apply it in template rather than comparing item ids.